# Некорректное имя при скачивании файла Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlet, download

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так. Сделал скачивание файлов.
Но почему-то при скачивании у файла имя меняется на `download`, хотя имя файла корректно.

код:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DownloadFile", urlPatterns = "/DownloadFile")
public class DownloadFile extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String path = request.getParameter("path");

        File file = new File(path);

        if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {

            ServletContext context = getServletContext();

            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(file.toString());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            response.setContentType(mimeType+";charset=UTF-8");

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а какой URL у самого сервлета?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman /download